# Binders for @JmsListener

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-jms, spring-cloud-stream

I am using a @JmsListener annotated method listen to JMS messages as shown below.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "Queue")
public void handleMessage(String message) {//implicit message type conversion
    System.out.println("received: "+message);
}
```

How do I convert this to Binders?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a production-ready JMS binder available. There's an alpha/experimental version [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms) supporting a limited number of brokers.